# Search Array of Objects Using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm 9 weeks into learning to program and I'm attempting to get into Hack Reactor. Currently I've hit a complete wall with a website I'm building and was hoping you might be able to help me (several days of testing and combing the internet - my previous strategy for getting around blocks - has proven fruitless).

In summary, I have an array of objects, each object is a teaching strategy which contains five properties. My goal is to add a search function that iterates over every object looking for keywords so a teacher could search the array of strategies. Currently I'm using the .map method to iterate a function over each object that checks the "tags" property for the keyword but for some reason or another I can't get the function to access "tags".

I've created a JSFiddle for you to check out: https://jsfiddle.net/jnemec/4ps8rLLx/

```
var myIdeas = [

   {name: "Choral",
   image: "img/xideas/choral.jpg",
   grade: [1, 9, 9],
   theory: "Theory:" + "<br>" + "Coming Soon.",
   tags: ["CFU", "literacy"]},

   {name: "Highlighters",
   image: "img/xideas/highlighters.jpg",
   grade: [2, 2, 3],
   theory: "Theory:" + "<br>" + "Coming Soon.",
   tags: ["manipulative", "differentiation"]},

];

var input = "literacy"

var output = myIdeas.map(function(input) {
   if (input == "tags") {
      output += "name";
   } else {
      return "no matches, please try again";}
});
```

Last thing - Hack Reactor requires my project use only vanilla JavaScript (no frameworks - which from what I've read would make this task easier).

Comment: Where does this code need to be able to run?

Comment: Is `input` the tags that you are trying to match?

Comment: Just put a console.log to see what `input` actually *is*. Then look up the docs for `map`. Debugging is a *critical* skill (step 1). Reading the docs is too (step 2). Always check your assumptions.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Thanks for the quick reply! I'm amazed. The code needs to run on my website. Here's the complete project on GitHub: https://github.com/jessejnemec/notsoterribleteacher

Comment: If you do what I say you'd have an answer yourself in minutes.

Comment: @nils - Yes, 'input' is representing what a teacher enters in the search bar on the main page (still need to create that component, focusing on getting the function working first)

Comment: (Also, if you want to grab matching names you need to access the `name` property of each object, which is not what you're doing. The docs for `map` will clear *everything* up in seconds.)

Comment: @DaveNewton - Ok. When I console.log 'input' I get what I assigned to input which is 'literacy'. So instead of searching 'name' I want to search 'tags' so that I can assign several categories to one object. For example - "Organizers" helps students who are English Language Learners, Special Ed, etc. Going to check the docs for map - do you recommend MDN?

Comment: You're putting the console log in the wrong place; you need to see `input` *inside the function you're passing to `map`*. MDN is probably the best source, although anything that lists the parameters the `map` callback expects would be adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know why you're doing it, in this case you shouldn't be `map()`'ing, you should be `filter()`'ing. The way you have this written right now isn't making good use of `map()` -- you might as well be using `forEach()`. And what you're returning from the callback doesn't make sense and isn't going to be accessible in a sensible way to detect and report to the user (although you could just use the value of `output` to detect the same condition).

Read about `map()`, `filter()`, and `forEach()` and think about how they apply to this situation and what kind of output you need.

In each invocation of the callback `input` is the object, so if you want to access the tags it'd be `input.tags`. If you want to access the outer `input` (your search term) you need to name one of them differently.

```js
var input = "literacy";

// `input` here declares a variable name that will be set to the current
// element of the array during each invocation of the callback.
var output = myIdeas.map(function(input) {
  // `input` now refers to the argument to this function. You've shadowed the
  // outer var of the same name and can no longer access it.
  // `input` is now an object from the array. If you want to access a prop like
  // `tags`, it's `input.tags`;
  if (input == "tags") {
    output += "name";
  } else {
    return "no matches, please try again";}
});
```

Comment: Or at least be `map`ping correctly; `filter` would require an extra step.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think that the result value "no matches, please try again" is intended as a global result value, not for an entry in the array. So `filter` seems to be the right choice as far as I can see.

Comment: Filter keeps elements matching the function; there's no need for map *or* filter if you're just going to use globals. If you're going to recommend `filter`, for my money, you'd clean up the entire example and make it look more like JS should look, no? YMMV, but IMO `filter` with a `map` to get the names and a `join` to create the final output is *way* cleaner, and avoids the globals. Might as well do it right.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, I agree. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't want to write the whole thing for the OP. There's more than one way to do it. You could start with `filter()` or `map()`, but since the OP clearly is not using `map()` for an informed reason I'm pointing them to `filter()` for their next step.

Comment: @JMM - Thanks for the help. I'm slow and need some time to play with this in JSFiddle.

Comment: @JesseNemec Take your time -- this is a good opportunity to learn some new stuff.

Comment: @JMM It's working! Heck yeah! Took me 47min but it's working. Now I've gotta get a variable from the user to be placed in the function...next task. Thank you for all the help everyone!